# Pre filled, partially not editable input field with simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Is it possible to create an input field, that is partially filled, but the filled part is not editable, and also, is not being submitted?
It may seem confusing, so a simple example.
I have a field, that looks like url. I want the user to specify, let's say, his name, so the field should look like this:

**www.something.com/users/** *input*

User should not be able to edit the bold part, only the "input" part. Also, I want to submit only the input, not the whole url. So basically I need something like this

```
<%= f.input :name, :not_editable_decoration: "www.something.com/users/" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">www.something.com/users/</span>
      <%= f.input :url, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above example use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) css.

You can put static url into some instance variable too in your controller.

```
@static_url = "www.something.com/users/"

<span class="input-group-addon"><%= @static_url %></span>
```

[link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/420/)

Comment: That helped.
But I wraped everything in the <%= f.input :user do %> code <% end %>, and changed  
f.input :url  
to  
f.input_field :url.  
Otherwise the prepend part was twice as hight as the input field.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to use the `show` action for `users` but you'd be able to use a [wildcard route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, except: :show do
   get "*input", to: :action, on: :collection #-> url.com/users/*input
end
```

This will pass a `params[:input]` variable to your action/view, which you'll be able to use in the form itself:

```
<%= f.input :name, :not_editable_decoration: "www.something.com/users/", value: params[:input] %>
```

Comment: The only problem here is to show that static url in input field.

Comment: Yep I forgot about that tbh. Maybe my answer with yours would help him resolve it